# How to get icon back in dock(Mac)?

Tags: macos, dock

I delete [image] by mistake. How can I get it back? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Finder, choose Applications folder in the sidebar and drag Launchpad to the Dock.

Comment: I cannot put that folder in mac as original icon. I can just put it as a folder like downloads

Comment: You mean you do not have a launchpad icon in your applications folder?

Edit: What version of OS X do you have?